# Reference local img in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

Here is my path to the image: `../src/assets/images/img_name.jpg"`
And path to the file.js: `src/file_name.js`
If I implement my code in file.js like this:

1. Import **img_name** from `"../src/assets/images/img_name.jpg"`
2. Then reference the img path in href tag: `<img src={img_name}></img>`

It will work but If I dont import and reference the img like this: `<img src='../src/assets/images/img_name.jpg'></img>`
It won't work no more. Can anyone explain why??
I use create-react-app

Comment: First of all, `img`s have no closing tag. Secondly, if the top path works why would you expect the second path to work? `/src/assets/images/img_name.jpg` probably doesn't also exist in the parent directory.

Comment: @ggorlen About img I think you can both use <img/> or <img></img>. Or at least it works for me. And both of the paths i used are the same: `../src/assets/images/img_name.jpg`. The problem is if I import it works, but if I use the path in src attribute it doesn't work.

Comment: Just because it works for you doesn't mean it's legal HTML. Browsers are able to fix broken HTML. Your last edit changed the paths.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you, I understand what you're saying. The path I edited is what I was the path that I wanna ask. And I only realise it after you said that lol...  Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to explictly import image file since webpack need proper loader for this file